# Android Parcel class error

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have the complete code copied as is from `android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference`. I am facing weird compilation errors for the following inner class:

Line #1 is the original code and i have added #Line 2

For Line #2

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String[]

and 
For uncommented Line #1

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String[]
>     - The method readStringArray(String[]) in the type Parcel is not applicable for the      arguments ()

```
private static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        Set<String> values;

        public SavedState(Parcel source) {
            super(source);
            values = new HashSet<String>();
            //String[] strings = source.readStringArray(); //Line #1
            String[] strings = source.readStringArray(values.toArray(new String[0])); //Line #2

            final int stringCount = strings.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < stringCount; i++) {
                values.add(strings[i]);
            }
        }

        public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
            dest.writeStringArray(values.toArray(new String[0]));
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
                new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

I am really amused by these compilation errors ! I am actually writing my own multi-select preference but facing the one and only error stated above and have no idea of solving it.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: read documentation ... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readStringArray(java.lang.String[])if you still don't get it read again ... and again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `readStringArray()` has no return value, which is why the compiler is complaining. You need to pass it a string array as a parameter and it fills the string array that you give it.

You call `readStringArray()` like this:

String[] things = new String[5]; // The array in the parcel is known to have 5 elements
   source.readStringArray(things);

This ONLY works if you know exactly how big the string array in the parcel is. If the array is always of a fixed size you can use this. If not, you will need to write the size of the array into the `Parcel` **before** you write the array, and then the reader of the `Parcel` can first read the size of the array, then create a suitably sized string array to receive the data.